# Client billing/client usage for microsoft cognitive services speech to text?

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm working on a website that is supposed to offer users to make use of azures cognitive services api. They can play audio or use their microphone to transform speech into text.

I'm currently using azures [js sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk) and technically it's working fine. However, I noticed a big shortcoming with this approach. The sdk connects through a websocket with the azure server, which exposes the subscription key to the client. So every member could theoretically read it out and sell it or alike.
Furthermore, if the client connects directly with azure, I have no secure way of preventing clients abusing the service. I need a way to measure roughly how much time a customer uses the service to take into account individual billing.

I could not find anything about that in the official documentation. So what are my options?

1. Should I redirect the clients' audio input to my own server, do some quantitative analysis, and then forward the input from a server side connection to azure? I fear with many concurrent customers, it might get laggy or connections might get dropped...
2. Is there any way to attach at least client ids or alike to azure websocket connection that I can read out somehow later?

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: It might depend how you manage your clients in your website: are they authenticated? Regarding option1, you will have difficulties to measure the usage even by passing through your server. If you have a limited number of clients, could you think about the option of having 1 key by client?

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks for your reply. Yes, they will be authenticated individually. No, giving each client an individual key will probably not be feasible. It might (potentially) be hundreds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your additional comment, I would suggest that you switch your implementation from using subscription key to using authentication tokens.

That would:

- generate a unique token for each client, based on 1 global subscription key
- not expose your subscription key to your clients
- restrict the use of the API, as the token is only valid for 10 minutes

> Each access token is valid for 10 minutes. You can get a new token at any time, however, to minimize network traffic and latency, we recommend using the same token for nine minutes.

See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#how-to-use-an-access-token) for global implementation. In a nutshell, you need to implement this token generation in your backend, and serve the page to your client with this token instead of the key.

Side note 1: be careful about the maximum number of concurrent requests (100 - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#online-transcription)).

Note 2: that will not help you bill clients given their usage as you have just 1 key and there is no way to identify distinct usages in it

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware that the js sdk also allows auth tokens. A temporal granularity of 10 minutes is perfectly reasonable. Just have to see whether I can possibly extend the concurrent usage number if necessary, but that's a different story.

Comment: There is an article and a process regarding this limit extension, you should definitely read it that will guide you through the process

Comment: Do you have the link by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that was just below my last link, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#detailed-description-quota-adjustment-and-best-practices

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot.